# Recursive URL Patterns CMS Style

Tags: django, django-urls

Whenever I learn a new language/framework, I always make a content management system...

I'm learning Python & Django and I'm stuck with making a URL pattern that will pick the right page.

For example, for a single-level URL pattern, I have:

```
url(r'^(?P<segment>[-\w]+)/$', views.page_by_slug, name='pg_slug'),
```

Which works great for urls like:

```
http://localhost:8000/page/
```

Now, I'm not sure if I can get Django's URL system to bring back a list of slugs ala:

```
http://localhost:8000/parent/child/grandchild/
```

would return parent, child, grandchild.

So is this something that Django does already? Or do I modify my original URL pattern to allow slashes and extract the URL data there?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because your regular expression does not allow middle '/' characters. Recursive definition of url segments pattern may be possible, but anyway it would be passed as a chunk to your view function.

Try this

```
url(r'^(?P<segments>[-/\w]+)/$', views.page_by_slug, name='pg_slug'),
```

and split `segments` argument passed to `page_by_slug()` by '/', then you will get `['parent', 'child', 'grandchild']`. I'm not sure how you've organized the page model, but if it is not much sophiscated, consider using or improving **flatpages** package that is already included in Django.

Note that if you have other kind of urls that does not indicate user-generated pages but system's own pages, you should put them before the pattern you listed because Django's url matching mechanism follows the given order.