# Regular expression url Django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I would like to have one or two urls in following format in django.

e.g. `/view/q/node/c/programming....`

Here `q`, `c`, etc are specific get params and latter on I'll be accessing them either through js or in view.

I have tried following pattern, but it didn't work out.

```
r'view/(P<q>\w+)/(P<c>\w+)/(P<l>\w+)/(P<o>\w+)/$'
```

I know that all the get params can be accessed in view if we have `?` in url. But I don't want to have `?` in url.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this? Please note that the url can be without any params also. e.g. `view/`.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe just need a carrot at the beginning? `r'^view/(P<q>\w+)/(P<c>\w+)/(P<l>\w+)/(P<o>\w+)/$'`  What error are you getting?

Comment: getting 404..added `^`..bt not working.

Comment: If they are get parameters, you dont have to match them in the regex. You can access them directly in the view by using `request.GET`

Comment: I don't want to have `?` in url..other wise I know simply `r'view/'` would be fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive URL Patterns CMS Style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072069/recursive-url-patterns-cms-style)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `?` from your [Named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups). From the Django docs:

> In Python regular expressions, the syntax for named regular-expression groups is
>
> `(?P<name>pattern)`, where name is the name of the group and pattern is some pattern to match.

Thus, referring to your example, it should be:

```
r'^view/(?P<q>\w+)/(?P<c>\w+)/(?P<l>\w+)/(?P<o>\w+)/$'
```

Comment: pls see updated question. Is there any way to omit `?` in url?

Comment: The `?` is part of the syntax for named regular-expression groups in Python. If you don't want to have a `?` in the regular expression, then you'll just have to use [Positional arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example).

Comment: Ok..got it..here's related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072069/recursive-url-patterns-cms-style